# Getting "Attribute "ref" must be declared for element type "property"."

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Kindly check line 21 I am getting error in the below XML

[Check this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6m0S1.png)

[Latest XML file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6m0S1.png)

Comment: Please provide more details?

Comment: @akash Check the image posted above ,click on  "enter image description here"

Comment: @akash I was trying to work with spring hibernate and was creating a context.xml file

Comment: Please show complete file (top is missing). You may need to change the DOCTYPE DTD version. Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/29721311/3503019

Comment: @akash I have updated the image click on "Check this image"

Comment: Please share your code (github?)

Comment: @akash her is my code - https://github.com/DipanjanSG/BankingApp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is how your correct spring bean configuration should look like -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans  
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"  
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"  
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd"> 

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">  
        <property name="driverClassName"  value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"></property>  
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Banking"></property>  
        <property name="username" value="root"></property>  
        <property name="password" value="root"></property>  
    </bean>  


<bean id = "mysessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" ></property>  

    <property name = "mappingResources">
    <list>
        <value>credentials.hbm.xml</value>
    </list> 
    </property>

    <property name = "hibernateProperties">
        <props>
          <prop key="hibernate.hbm.ddl.auto">update</prop>
          <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>  
          <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>


</bean>

<bean id="template" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate">  
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="mysessionFactory"></property>  
    </bean>  

    <bean id="d" class="com.javatpoint.EmployeeDao">  
    <property name="template" ref="template"></property>  
    </bean>  
</beans>
```

Comment: not working, click on "Latest XML file" , have attached scrnsht

Comment: if it is not an issue can I mail you he code. If yes kindly give me ur email-id

Comment: can also answer this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61910080/getting-error-property-driverclassname-threw-exception-nested-exception-is-j   @akash